# Vertex AI Batch Predictions with CSV input

Tags: google-cloud-ml

We have been trying to run Batch predictions using a CSV stored in GCS as input, and a model pickle file stored in GCS. Unfortunately, however, we cant seem to get the predictions to work with a CSV input.

We created a test CSV that is a 16x16 identity matrix, with a header row.

EG:

```
input_1,input_2,input_3
1.0,0.0,0.0
0.0,1.0,0.0
0.0,0.0,1.0
```

The file is formatted in this way, with more cols and rows.

Our model expects 16 features.

With this CSV and our Model Pickle in GCS, we launched a batch prediction request from the Console UI.

The job ran for a little while and appears successful in the Pipelines UI, however no results are returned and the resulting error file in GCS is empty.

I checked the Vertex Predictions Documentation and it seems my CSV is in the same format as that demonstrated there.

Using this model, but with the formatted JSON input - we do get a result, so I don't think it is the model.

Is this a known issue?

Has anyone managed to run a batch prediction on Vertex AI with a CSV as input?

Comment: It should works without header.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that quote to columns are required unless those column names are numbers.
So you need to quote your headers:

```
"input_1","input_2","input_3"
```

There is a mistake in the [Vertex AI batch request input documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/batch-predictions#batch_request_input) as the example shown doesn't have quotes and the documentation should be updated soon (I have reported it).

A fix was indeed released recently but it had to be rolled back and it is not clear yet if this quote requirement will finally be changed.

Comment: I clicked the link but looks like they changed that page too... the section you are linking to is gone. I am not able to find any csv example of how input data should go in the docs....

Answer (score 0):

This was a product bug. Google released a fix last week. Please retest with CSV, it should work.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.